# How load data from DB/XML to Model in MVVM

Tags: orm, mvvm, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

Hi I would like to know how correct initialize Model from DB in MVVM.

I use Caliburn.Micro Framework, for dependency injection I can use MEF or Castle Windsor and as ORM I can use Entity Framework or NHibernate.

I have some model class it can be POCO

```
public class SomeModel{}
```

Also I have some view model class

```
public interface IViewModelA
{
ModelA SomeModel{get;set;}
}

public class ViewModelA : ScreenViewModel, IViewModelA
{
 public ModelA SomeModel{get;set;}
}
```

I bind properties of SomeModel on view. I think this is not good view.

I would like to know how correct load data from repository (XML, DB-with ORM) to Model.

Create some another class for example ModelManager init view models properties here?

**This sample is with Caliburn + MEF**

```
public interface IManager{}

[Export(typeof(IManager)]
public class Manager :Screen,IManager
{
  //import dependencies with MEF   
  [Import]
  public IViewModelA VMA{get;set;}

  public void Init()
  {
   VMA.SomeModelA=//load from DB
  }

}
```

Or what is correct and common way?

I would like see some simple sample from real world with Caliburn.Micro + ORM (NHibernate/ Entity Framework)+ IoC (MEF/Castle Windsor).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well. You need to find information about DDD and Repository Pattern. In short a Repository is way you can access you data of some type. For instance you can have:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers();
    Customer GetCustomerById(Guid aId);
}

public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DbCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private DbConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public DbCustomerRepository(DbConnection aConnection)
    {
        Connection = aConnection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        // Do your query to DB here.
        yield break;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomerById(Guid aId)
    {
        // Do your query to DB here.
        return null;
    }
}

public class XmlCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private string FilePath { get; set; }

    public XmlCustomerRepository(string aFilePath)
    {
        FilePath = aFilePath;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        // Find all customers in a XML-file.
        yield break;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomerById(Guid aId)
    {
        // Find a specific customer in a XML-file.
        return null;
    }
}
```

You need to pass in your ViewModel constructor an ICustomerRepository.
    public class CustomerListViewModel
    {
        private ICustomerRepository Repository { get; set; }

```
    public CustomerListViewModel(ICustomerRepository aRepository)
    {
        Repository = aRepository;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            if (mCustomers == null)
            {
                IEnumerable<Customer> lCustomers = Repository.GetCustomers();
                mCustomers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(lCustomers);

            }

            return mCustomers;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> mCustomers;
}
```

You should configure your IoC-container with mapping of service ICustomerRepository to a concrete Component (for example DbCustomerRepository) as well as register your CustomerListViewModel as self.
But it is just a beginning of the story. You need to store your changed data in the data source (DB, XML etc.). Of course you can add a method on repository to save data but it is against S.O.L.I.D. principles. Better to use the Unit of Work pattern from DDD. In some point you will need to customize Customer to add some additional properties and methods for the display means. Fill free to create a wrapper around Customer - CustomerViewModel.
Something like that.